# Верстка с сеткой и без нее

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Знаю что уже всех достал с вопросами про сетку:) но считаю что это тема важная и скорее всего этот вопрос последний. Собственно: Правильно ли я понимаю что responsive верстка без сетки и с ней отличаются тем что в первом варианте размер блоков в контейнере задается просто в процентах а во втором относительно определенного кол-ва колонок в сетке? Мне со стороны показалось что это - самое существенное различие. Прав ли я и есть ли еще какие то нюансы? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: нет, не правы, вы сейчас сравниваете bootstrap <= 3 и bootstrap 4. У обоих сетка, просто в старых были float, теперь flex. Любой ячеечный подход, хоть таблицы – это сетка, вообще понятие очень размытое, и скорее это дизайнерская тема.

Comment: В обоих случаях будет ширина в процентах, посмотри на сетку bootstrap там ширина колонок задана в процентах. Сетка упращает создание структуры сайта и позиционированния блоков для дизайнеров и разработчиков.

Comment: @E_K Я в принципе догадывался об этом но проблема в том что изучив теорию сеток я вообще перестал понимать как тогда правильно верстать без них. И существует ли тогда вообще понятие верстать не по сетке. Судя по вашему комментарию различий в этих двух методах нет. :( p.s. у меня информационный шок